# Анимированное увеличение числа на Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, counter

На сайте wordpress вывожу динамическое число через шорткод в wp-editor, так:

```
[lifetime]
```

Нужно сделать анимированное увеличение числа. Максимальное значение числа не известно, т.к. число динамическое.

Как добавить [такую анимацию](http://jsfiddle.net/uvzx0aLg/) увеличения числа на сайте wordpress?

**UPD**

Суть проблемы как передать переменную `$lifetime` которая используется в `functions.php`, и вызывается через шорткод `[lifetime]` в админке wordpress.

Comment: А в чем проблема? Что не получается? Если не получается передать число, то можно так - http://jsfiddle.net/uvzx0aLg/47/

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev возможно не так поняла, сделала так http://jsfiddle.net/uvzx0aLg/48/ выводит `NaN`. суть проблемы как передать переменную `$lifetime` которая используется в `functions.php`. шорткод `[lifetime]` указан прямо в верстке в админке

Comment: на jsfiddle же не подставится lifetime, в вордпрессе должен работать и внутри h3 замените lifetime на число для старта отсчета

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev спасибо за помощь, но у меня почему-то не срабатывает, добавила число http://jsfiddle.net/uvzx0aLg/49/. сначала выводит `5` а потом `NaN`...

Comment: на jsfiddle же не подставится lifetime, в вордпрессе должен работать

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev jsfiddle я привела для наглядности (показать что я накодировала). значение не выводится на моем сайте

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev спасибо, работает. надо было убрать кавычки у `data-target`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var currentNumber = $('.js-number-lifetime').text(),
  targetNumber = $('.js-number-lifetime').attr('data-target');
$({
  numberValue: currentNumber
}).animate({
  numberValue: targetNumber
}, {
  duration: 1000,
  easing: 'linear',
  step: function() {
    $('.js-number-lifetime').text(Math.ceil(this.numberValue));
  }
});
```